# When loading richTextBox with a plaintext file(.txt) it loses the formatting

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, richtextbox

well basically i just load a text file which is in the project container using

```
richTextBox1->LoadFile("fileName.txt",System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBoxStreamType::PlainText);
```

but when outputing it loses all the '\n' 's (basically no endlines are left in text).

I Know that windows save their endlines with '\r''\n' or something like that, so i think that it loses the '\n' because it thinks its different formatting or something but I can't figure out how to bypass this without opening the file and converting it to String ^ first and then directly loading it to the richtextbox.

EDIT: example:

original text:

line1

line2

line3

-After loading file:

line1 line2 line3

Comment: Probably something wrong with the file in a way that we can't see.  StreamReader works harder to fix line-ending problems, so try using richTextBox1->Text = System::IO::File::ReadAllText("fileName.txt") instead.

Comment: Seems to work, thanks.It's very peculiar because files i made by hand it loads just fine, but if i make them in a certain way with code they do this.Well it's all probably formatting, thanks again.

Comment: Well, rather best to fix the code that creates the file.  The rough diagnostic is that it writes "\r" as the line-ending instead of "\r\n".  Use a hex viewer to verify.